# Does the royal family know about the Wizarding World?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Half-Blood Prince*, it's revealed that the Minister of Magic tells the Muggle
Prime Minister about wizards and witches.

Does the M.O.M. also tell the King and Queen of Britain, about the Wizarding World?

Comment: the book explicitly states that PM would never tell anyone else because "who on earth would believe him"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Book Canon

There are no canon confirmations (within the Harry Potter books or tie-in books) that the Queen of England has any specific knowledge of the Wizarding world. The closest we get is a mention that the muggle Prime Minister is kept abreast of certain magical events. Since a major part of his/her formal role is to [keep the King or Queen apprised](http://www.royal.gov.uk/MonarchUK/QueenandGovernment/QueenandPrimeMinister.aspx) of the "matters of the day" that affect the UK, it would be surprising if he/she *wasn't* made aware.

I personally veer onto the side of yes, they would be aware but without any real confirmation all we have is pure conjecture.

---

### Film canon

There's a blink-and-you'll-miss-it mention of the Queen in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone.

> "***Queen's Corgi Turns into Hamster***"

[image]

It's unclear if her corgi being turned into a hamster resulted in her becoming aware of the wizarding world.

---

### Not really canon at all

There was a sketch made to celebrate the Queen's 80th Birthday. When her handbag goes missing, the muggle Prime Minister directs a message to Hogwarts to help return it. Although there's no special mention of the Queen actually communicating with wizards, Harry Hill takes the part of **The Keeper of Her Majesty's Owls**, suggesting that the Crown not only knows about the Wizarding world but also has a semi-regular method of communication.

Comment: -3 for reminding me of the Holiday Special :(

Comment: The Prime Minister does not report everything to the Queen (or King). As an example, if I am not wrong, the Secret Services refer directly to the Prime Minister, who only transfer relevant information to the Queen. So it may depend on the Prime Minister's decision to inform the Queen about the wizarding world.

Comment: It is my opinion that the royal records very likely mention the presence of magic in the world and it would therefore be likely that the prime minister communed with the queen on such matters. I would guess the minister of magic likely views himself as one of the prime minister's sub-minister, though autonomous, independently managed and appointed.

Comment: @escoce - There's no evidence whatsoever that the Minister for Magic views himself as anything other than the leader of his own nation,  albeit one that largely exists within another nation.

Comment: @Richard would be why I prefaced this with, "it is my opinion..." As well as making it a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Pottermore's article about Ministers for magic says that Evangeline Orpington (in office 1849-1855) was "A good friend of Queen Victoria's, who never realised she was a witch, let alone Minister for Magic."
This suggests that the Royal family is not aware of the wizarding world, but this could have changed by now.

Comment: But that could also be read to mean that the Queen was aware of witches and that there was a Minister of Magic, but had no idea it was her good friend.

Answer (score 0):

The wikia article on the [International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/International_Statute_of_Wizarding_Secrecy) claims that

> In the Great Britain, the newly-created Ministry of Magic attempted to liaise with the Muggle British Monarch (then jointly William III and Mary II) via a special Ministry Delegation, begging them for the protection of wizards under Muggle law. The failure of this attempt at official recognition and protection seems to have been the final straw that forced wizardkind to voluntarily move in the opposite direction toward secrecy.

If true, that would mean that the British Kings and Queens were, at least at one time, aware of the wizarding world.

The source cited for this claim is the old jkrowling.com site, but that site seems to no longer include this information.

As Valorum mentions in another answer, the muggle Prime Minister is required to brief the monarch on important "matters of the day", so it seems likely that, in modern times, the Queen would hear of the wizarding world from the Prime Minister rather than directly from the Ministry of Magic.