# Is the Ministry of Magic part of the British Government?

Tags: harry-potter, government

It's not, by its own admission, a Government in its own right, but just a ministry:

> (in certain countries) a government department headed by a minister.
>   "the Ministry of Defence"
>     synonyms:   government department, department, bureau, agency, office
>   "the ministry for foreign affairs"
>   ~ *Google*

Did JKR intend to make the MoM part of the British Government? Or is this a mistake of language?

I do recognise that the Muggle PM in the later books does not recognise Scrimgeour, but I don't find this conclusive (Wizards could be classified above the PM, or just be on a Need to Know basis)

Comment: No. The British government can barely manage to run itself in the mundane, muggle world. If it had *any* oversight or relationship with the Ministry of Magic we'd all be dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No. Absolutely not.**

I see no reason to presume that the Ministry of Magic is anything other than a wholly separate government, one that possesses its own Executive, Legislative and Judicial functions along with its own currency, international policy, etc etc.

If I can quote from the [pottermore article](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Ministers_for_Magic) on the Ministry of Magic:

> *The Muggle Prime Minister has no part in appointing the Minister for
>   Magic, whose election is a matter only for the magical community
>   themselves. **All matters relating to the magical community in Britain
>   are managed solely by the Minister for Magic, and he has sole
>   jurisdiction over his Ministry.** Emergency visits to the Muggle Prime
>   Minister by the Minister for Magic are announced by a portrait of
>   Ulick Gamp (first Minister for Magic) that hangs in the Muggle Prime
>   Minister's study in number 10 Downing Street.*

Since in the UK, all authority ultimately flows from the Queen, any organisation that doesn't fall within her jurisdiction is *by definition* **not part of the UK government.**

Comment: Your comment about the Queen make this sounds technically correct. The best kind of correct.

Comment: But **why does the MfM need to visit the PM if his Ministry isn't part of the government?**

Comment: @randal'thor - To quote from the same article; "*This is perhaps due to a feeling, on the part of wizards, that unless they are seen to manage themselves competently, the Muggles might try to interfere."*. I'm assuming the visits are a courtesy call and to stop the muggle PM from making it a priority to kill those pesky wizards.

Comment: ah that would be interesting if the royal family knew about the existence of magic, i bet they would have had dealings with wizards prior to parliament being set up .

Comment: @Himarm - Already [asked](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76464/does-the-royal-family-know-about-the-wizarding-world/76466#76466) and answered

Comment: Is that the same Gamp who made the law of Elemental Transfiguration?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - It's not clear. There are other Gamps mentioned in the text; http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gamp